# How width in percentage is getting assigned to div?

Tags: html, css

I have main div and inside that i have 3 divs and each have individual width in percentage. So i got divs with 20%, 80% and 100% respectively. 
Working with them so far i realised that if I have given then width of 200% all together then it divide browser width in two equal parts and first half is considered 100% and other one 100%. Then rest of percentage distribution happens. I am new to CSS but want to make this clear. Is my understanding correct and that's why my code is working correctly? Is there any disadvantage of doing so?

```css
.main {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.column1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
}

.column2 {
  width: 80%;
}

.column3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.clear-both {
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-style: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row main">

  <div class="column1">CODE</div>

  <div class="column2 ">NAME</div>
  <div class="column3">TOTAL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem here and what you want to achieve?  

Comment: I am getting what i want to i.e. i want these 3 columns to be in one row. But i am not sure this is right way to do that and also is there any possibility of breaking of ui if i do it in this way, as my total width is 200%?

Comment: keep your parent div 100% not 200% .. 200% like width are for horizontal websites or sliders like things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong.

Keep following things in mind.

1- Parent/ main div should have appropriate width in percent or pixels. if  you don't assign a width then it will take width automatically depending on contents of width.

2- If you are assigning width in percent to child divs (column1, column2 etc) then  total of child divs should not exceed 100%. If it exceeds then you will not get desired/appropriate results.

3- You need to use floats or display:inline-block to place all child divs/elements in one row.

```css
.main {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.column1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

.column2 {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

.column3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row main">
  <div class="column1">CODE</div>

  <div class="column2 ">NAME</div>
  <div class="column3">TOTAL</div>
</div>
```

If you are using padding or borders then you may need  to use
 box-sizing: border-box.

Answer (score 2):

if you use flexbox, it makes it clearer for you instead of using `float`s mixed with `position`,

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.main {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column1 {
  flex: 0 20%;
  background: red
}

.column2 {
  flex: 0 80%;
  background: green
}

.column3 {
  flex: 0 100%;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="column1">CODE</div>
  <div class="column2 ">NAME</div>
  <div class="column3">TOTAL</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** OP's comment

> I want these 3 columns to be in one row. Working with my code too but
>   total width of main div is 200%. is there any possibility of breaking
>   of ui if i do it in this way

You can do this way:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.main {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex
}

.column1,
.column3 {
  flex: 0 20%;
  background: yellow
}

.column2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="column1">CODE</div>
  <div class="column2 ">NAME</div>
  <div class="column3">TOTAL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want these 3 columns to be in one row. Working with my code too but total width of main div is 200%. is there any possibility of breaking of ui if i do it in this way

Comment: Ok. you still need to keep Total of child divs to 100%..

Total width of column1, column2 and column3 should not be greater than parent div in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) grid system.

> Grid systems are used for creating page layouts through a series of
>   rows and columns that house your content.

So you can easily manage your layout depending on which device you are using :

1. .col-lg*  classes refer to large sized devices.
2. .col-md*  classes refer to medium sized devices .
3. .col-xs*  classes refer to small sized devices.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2  col-xs-2  bg-warning">CODE</div>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 bg-primary">NAME</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 bg-success">TOTAL</div>
 </div>
```